# PHPExcel: Is it possible to remove a whole row (not only empty cells)

Tags: php, phpexcel

I work with PHPExcel, and I want to remove (copletlly delete a row).

I currently use `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($i);` which does empty the cells, but I want to completlly remove the rows.

I run a function that uses this code line, and right after it I check for the last row with content (using `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();` - and I get the last row as if nothing wasn't deleted.

(Cells are empty tough... )

Comment: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($i);` should remove the row, shuffling all rows below up a step, although it does leave an empty row at the bottom of the worksheet..... it should not simply empty the cells, and I can't replicate a situation where it does this unless you are just calling it against the last row in the worksheet

Comment: @MarkBaker are you 100% sure?

Comment: I have yet to see a case where it does not work as I've outlined above.... if you can present me with a working example that demonstrates otherwise, then I may be convinced that there's a bug which needs addressing.... but unless I see that evidence, I can only go on the results of my own tests

Comment: But a call to `getHighestRow()` will not change, no matter how many rows you add or delete.... this value is read from the spreadsheet file on load, and will not then change

Comment: If you want an accurate row count, then you have the `getHighestDataRow()` method, which counts dynamically when executed

Comment: And this my friend, solved my problem! 
Thanks a lot for your help! :D

Comment: @MarkBaker Why don't you include some way to avoid the rows that have  `NULL` or `Blank` in all columns? Like we can set `$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(False);` to avoid taking the whole column that is `NULL` or `Blank` !